# Why doesn't blood sound like \ˈblüd\?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The pronunciation of *blood* is  \'bləd\ while words such as *moon* and *spoon* (with double 'o') are pronounced as \ˈmün\ and \ˈspün.

Why isn't *blood* pronounced like \ˈblüd\ ?

Comment: There are also "brood" and "loot", which are both pronounced with "ü"

Comment: /muːn/ and /spuːn/ -  /uː/ ːit's a long back vowel sound (Br English) hence the /ː/ after the symbol of the vowel sound. In modern English flood /flʌd/ is also pronounced like blood /blʌd/.

Comment: @JanDvorak: like "goose" and "choose" and most English words with a double "o" in their spelling. But not all, "good" is another exception to the  /uː/ sound, it's has a short back vowel sound: /ɡʊd/.

Comment: Why don't _hearth_ and _earth_ rhyme? Or _said_ and _maid_?

Comment: From ELL's perspective, the simple answer is "the pronunciation of English words isn't particularly related to how they are spelled". Consequently I think this would be a better fit on ELU where they can discuss the etymology of the word.

Comment: Because [spelling is chaotic](http://www.mipmip.org/tidbits/pronunciation.shtml). There actually are reasons though.

Comment: What with all the backslashes and non/sub/anti-standard markings? Standard phonemics would be /blʌd/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attempt to a historical explanation could be found in the [Great Vowel Shift](http://eweb.furman.edu/~mmenzer/gvs/what.htm). Before the Great Vowel Shift that started around the 14th century  "oo" was pronounced [oː] and it then evolved into [uː], see [chart](http://eweb.furman.edu/~mmenzer/gvs/what.htm). Evolution continued and some words evolved in different ways and are now pronounced differently. But as to why they have evolved differently I expect we can only make guesses. About "flood" and "blood", nowadays pronounced with a short */ʌ/* we know that at one point in time they both used to be spelt respectively *floud* and *bloud*, could that be a reason why their pronunciations have evolved in a similar manner?

You might find those posts on linguistics.stackexchange interesting:
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/how-do-linguists-determine-at-which-point-the-great-vowel-shift-was-complete
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/4181/637

or this page on the internet in addition to the one given in my first paragraph:
http://marymoore2012.weebly.com/1/post/2013/04/english-as-a-global-language-great-vowel-shift.html

and [this](http://books.google.fr/books?id=fNfebt79zdwC&pg=PT198&lpg=PT198&dq=%22%20food,%20good,%20and%20blood%22&source=bl&ots=aLIHBIcsYC&sig=Q6rjbbSYVeS2kQzGmIv3TA5Og7I&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=VsyqUu2SAdGBhAfenIHACQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22%20food,%20good,%20and%20blood%22&f=false) page from *[The History of English Spellin](http://books.google.fr/books?id=fNfebt79zdwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false)g*

Answer (score 8):

### Many vowel pairs have more than one sound

- *oo* has at least three: *hoot*, *hood*, *flood*.
- *ou* has at least three: *pound, soup, double*.
- *ea* has at least three: *peal, bread, break*. (In fact, the word *read* uses two of these: *I **read** a book yesterday; I will **read** another book tomorrow*.)

### This gets even more varied when the vowel pair precedes an *r* or *gh*

- Consider *poor, earn, pear, court, scour*
- When *ou* is followed by *gh*, things get ridiculously varied: *thought, though, through, tough, cough, bough*

### Let's not forget about when *w* functions as a vowel

- That's why words like *bow* and *row* rhyme with BOTH *know* and *now*. (*"Tie a **bow**, then take a **bow**,"* for example).

### Some of these pronunciations vary by region

- In the U.S., some areas of the country pronounce "route" as a homophone of "root" (which rhymes with "toot"), while others pronounce it as a homophone of "rout" which rhymes with "out").

Comment: the oo in *hood* is different than the one in *foot*?   News to me.

Comment: Yeah, this is a great answer (+1!) but I agree with @Hellion that I've never heard *hood* and *foot* pronounced with a different vowel sound.

Comment: @Hellion - Nope; I pronounce them the same, too. Just a mix-up when I was picking my examples. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: One of those things where I couldn't really be sure if it was a mistake, or a genuine regional thing I'm just not in the right region for....  :-)  (I'd already +1'd you anyway.)